# Calculating Cronbach's alpha for pre-post scales separately or together?

Tags: intervention-analysis, cronbachs-alpha

I am measuring a self-efficacy (SE) score by measuring 7 sub-scales for pre and post intervention.For example, for a participant, I have the SE score by measuring 7 sub-scales before the intervention, and I measure the same 7 sub-scale after the intervention. My question is, for calculating the Cronbach's alpha as a statistic for the internal reliability among the sub-scales, how do I proceed? Do I calculate the Cronbach's alpha for the pre-intervention and post-intervention separately (so two Cronbach alphas)? Or, I consider the 14 scales all together to obtain one Cronbach alpha? Which one makes more sense? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:  alpha measures the extent to which different indicators are measuring the same essential thing.  Do you want, or do you expect, pre and post scales to be measuring the same thing?  (Do you expect there to be any change?)

Comment: @rolando2 The pre (7 scales) and the post (same 7 scales) are measuring the same variable SE. Due to the intervention, I am expecting an increase in the post scales. In other words, I am expecting increased SE after the intervention.

Comment: I should have said, Do you expect 'pre' responses to be a fine substitute for 'post'?  If so, all you would need would be a single, 14-item alpha.

Comment: @rolando2 What do you exactly mean by 'fine substitute'?

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity: I appreciate this question, and based on the "hints" that others have provided, it sounds like you should compute alpha separately for pre and post. A rule of thumb I've seen in other forums like this is that calculating internal consistency each time you deploy a measurement is generally a good practice. See this thread from Research Gate, for example: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Calculate-Cronbach-alpha-in-repeated-measures-design

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/354074)